# New to Xbox 360 - less options after signing in

Tags: xbox-360, xbox-network

So I bought myself a Xbox 360 Slim and signed myself in with my Microsoft account to have a Xbox live account. But now the menu differs from the one I had at the start, I only have 4 tabs (home, community, games&apps and settings). Not only that, but before I would have Netflix and Amazon Prime apps being displayed for download, but now I can't download any of them, neither can I download some of the demo games I wanted to try out before I signed up. I wanted to ask if there is something I can do about this, because I would like to have some apps on it and play demo games that are a bit newer. Is it maybe because the support of the Xbox 360 is coming closely to an end?

**EDIT**
Images:

[My Menu](https://postimg.org/image/p02yjpn8z/)

[Menu when I am not signed in](https://postimg.org/image/nukwy5gfl/)

[Apps that I can't download](https://postimg.org/image/ay60ni14f/)

Comment: What do you mean "now the menu differs from the one I had at the start"? When was "at the start"?

Comment: Well, when I sing out I get the same screen like when I booted first the devise without my profile. There I have Bing search, homepage, community, games, movies&tv, music, apps and settings... But as soon as I sign in I am only stuck with home, community, games&apps and setting. And I am not able to find stuff like demo games and apps like I could before I would sign in.

Comment: When you say you can't download anything, that's because you can't find it? Or because there's actually a problem when you attempt it?

Comment: So I went again in the menu to see if I can find Netflix, but sadly there isn't even an app search. Seems like I can't download them... I also singed out, pinned Amazon prime video and then signed in again. I found then the app in my pins, but I can't download it... I live in Germany and I know that atleast Netflix and Amazon prime works here, because I use Amazon and a lot of friend use Netflix, but I can't find the app. And my console settings, region and language are also both on German.

Comment: There's no Search Apps button on the Apps page? That sounds like a problem. Is there any way you can get a screenshot uploaded? Or just a photo of the screen? I understand it would be in German.

Comment: Oh, I ment to say the "bing" search function. I have now uploaded some images of the menu before and after I sign in.

Comment: Those screenshots look fine. You should be able to get apps and games without issue based on what I'm looking at.

Comment: So, a friend of my mine signed in with his account and his and mine menu look different. The problem seems that my account is linked to Croatia and I need to change my region in the xbox/microsoft settings online. To do so I need to wait bcs I issued a security check and need to wait 2 more weeks until I can make some changes. But after that I would be able to download apps like Amazon Video and Netflix like the Demos I want (which my friend can download too from his account).

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to find demo games and apps such as Netflix on the Games and Apps tabs.

Here's a tutorial on getting Netflix set up, from Microsoft: [Set up and use the Netflix app on Xbox 360](http://support.xbox.com/en-US/xbox-360/apps/netflix-setup).

Update after screenshots were added:

Your screenshots look fine. It seems like you should be able to get games and apps without issue. On the Apps page, you would use Apps dursuchen to browse apps and Apps suchen to search for apps. I assume the games are located under Spiele, which should have similar options.